# Getting MailSendException in Grails Mail

Tags: email, grails, jakarta-mail

I am getting the following error:

**ERROR**

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages:javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address; message exceptions (1)     are:
Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address
```

**CONFIG**

```
grails.mail.host = "xx.xx.com"
grails.mail.port = 25
grails.mail.from = "xx@xx.com"
grails.mail.username = "xx@xx.com"
grails.mail.password = "xxx"
grails.mail.props = ["mail.smtp.auth": "true",
    "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port": "25",
    "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback": "false"]
```

**CODE**

```
try {
    sendMail {
      to "${params.emailTo}"
      subject "${params.emailSubject}"
      body "${params.emailMessage}"
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    println e
  }
```

Comment: What is your code ? Be more spesific when you asking ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLUTION* **changed too this and it worked

```
 sendMail {
 to "${params.emailTo}"
 from "xx@xx.com"
 subject "${params.emailSubject}"
 body "${params.emailMessage}"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `CONFIG` section, in the line

```
grails.mail.from = "example@example.com"
```

You forgot the word 'default'. The correct is:

```
grails.mail.default.from="example@example.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the port that you have mentioned in the code. Check if the mail server on your machine is sending data from that port.

Comment: i use the same port in outlook